# Visual studio code changes format (React-JSX)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

I've the following snippet in my index.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <div style = { styles.app } >
            Welcome to React!
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The code works, but every time I save (ctrl+s) visual studio format the jsx like that:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( < div style = { styles.app } >
            Welcome to React!
            <
            /div>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? thanks

Comment: Do you have a formatting extension installed? I copied your code into a new  js file and it formats correctly with vs code. So if you have an extension installed I would say uninstall it, if not then maybe you need to update vscode

Answer (score 359, accepted):

In the end what did the trick was changing the file format from JavaScript to JavaScript React on the bottom toolbar.
I'm publishing it here for future reference since I didn't find any documentation on this topic.

[image]

In addition to the above. If you click 'Configure File Association for .js' you can set all .js files to Javascript React

Comment: is there a way to enable this by default on all js files. Say, maybe a settings/ config file

Comment: @Kenshinman Would like to know this as well! I am only working with React but my files are all .js and not .jsx

Comment: thanks, you can also consider to put     "files.associations": { "*.js": javascriptreact" } to the settings.json

Comment: @khoailang Looks like that works for me, it just appears we are missing the opening " for the value of javascriptreact. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 72):

change vscode preferences settings > user settings below:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.js":"javascriptreact"
    }
```

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Answer (score 31):

You can prevent VSC from incorrectly formatting your JSX by adding an association in your **settings.json**

`Code` > `Preferences` > `Settings`

In the settings window search for **associations**, click **edit in settings.json** and then add:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

Comment: By doing this, it will apply to all `.js`. files. Will it be any problem to all the other `.js`.files?

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, saving the file with a **.jsx** extension resolves this in vscode.

I had the same challenge and I am hoping to discover a better way of handling this issue in vscode.

I noticed your suggested work-around has to be done each time you open the react file with an extension of **.js**

Comment: is their any other way to give powers of JSX to JS  ?

Answer (score 8):

Open the **Visual Studio Code** Settings. Refer the image below to see how to navigate to the settings.

[image: Open Vscode Settings]

Once the **settings tab** is open. If you want to make the settings changes for all the projects then select the **User sub tab**, if only for current project then select the **Workspace sub tab**.

[image: Add file Associations]

type "file associations" in the search text box and press Enter.

Click on **add item**.

- set **Item** : **.js*
- set **Value** : *javascriptreact*

Above changes will start associating all `*js` files in the project as **javascript React files**.

Next open any `.js` file in your project and right click and select Format Document. If you have multiple formatters then associate your favorite formatter. I have used **Prettier** to handle my formatting.

Comment: how do you change the default formatter?  Mine is set to C#, but there is no formatter for react listed even though it's selected at the bottom of the VSCode window

Comment: Install the extension for Prettier from  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

In VSCode settings you can set the value for the file to set your default formatted as shown below
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }
}

Answer (score 5):

Install Prettier (if not installed by default) and try to add this to your user or workplace settings:

`"prettier.jsxBracketSameLine": true`

Do not put linebreak between return and the returned JSX expression.

Trigger autoformat `(Alt+Shift+F)` and check if works.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this but finally found a solution. This is my settings.json

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
    "window.zoomLevel": 1,
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "javascript": "javascriptreact",
        "vue-html": "html"
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,
    "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true,
    "beautify.ignore": [
        "**/*.js",
        "**/*.jsx"
    ],
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true
}
```

I added

```
"beautify.ignore": ["**/*.js","**/*.jsx"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me-

I clicked on the Language mode (Javascript React) at the bottom of the screen

[image]

Then chose the Configure React Javascript Language based setting option

[image]

Then changed the javascript react default formatter to prettier as shown in the pic.

[image]

That pretty much did it for me after I saved the React file.

Answer (score 4):

**Make sure you dont have multiple javascript formatters enabled in your current workspace. (You have to disable the rest of them for your current workspace).**

**react-beautify** mostly does the magic but fails if you have some other JS formatter/beautifier already installed.

In my case, I had react-beautify and JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension installed. I had to disable the JS-CSS-HTML Formatter for my current workspace.

Comment: how do you disable a formatter for a single workspace?

Comment: Here is how you do it > (1) Go to the Extensions section. 
(2) Locate the JS-CSS-HTML Formatter (3) Head over to the Disable drowdown menu (4) There must be a section saying Disable (Workspace)

Answer (score 2):

I just added all the combinations mentioned above.

1. added this

```js
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

2. added this also

```js
"beautify.ignore": ["**/*.js","**/*.jsx"]
```

3. Deleted additional js formatting
4. installed prettier
5. turn ON prettier and formatting

Answer (score 1):

You can install an extension like react-beautify that helps you format your jsx code.

It is found [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=taichi.react-beautify)

This extension wraps prettydiff/esformatter to format your javascript, JSX, typescript, TSX file.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already installed this extension it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable the JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension in VSC. only solution to this problem

Comment: Definitely not the only solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

Prettier is an opinionated code formatter. It enforces a consistent style by parsing your code and re-printing it with its own rules that take the maximum line length into account, wrapping code when necessary.
include :
JavaScript
TypeScript
Flow
JSX
JSON
CSS
SCSS
Less
HTML
Vue
Angular
GraphQL
Markdown
YAML
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, then I found out it was caused by 'beautify' extension. After I uninstalled the extension, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

After reading many great suggestions and workarounds, I discovered that I could simply place my mouse arrow down over the bright blue horizontal bar at the bottom of VSCode editor window - right click - which opens a popup list window - and deselected = "Editor Indentation".

Answer (score 0):

You can double click `JavaScript` in the Status Bar at the bottom of VSCode, and then change the format from JavaScript to React (Choose `React` in the Select language mode to associate with `'.jsx'`)

Answer (score 0):

[Bottom bar in VS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOTxx.png)

I found simple solution as the html tags we are using are jsx , so i changed javascript to javascript jsx for each .js file to save as jsx in bottom bar.

Disclaimer : May be this is an instant soltution for those who are just beginning with React , jsx.

Answer (score -3):

add this in your .js code,

```js
/* prettier-ignore */
```