# How to prevent insert spaces in JSX code

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I have just started learning React Native. I am using Visual Studio Code for editing.
Whenever I save my file it is inserting spaces in my JSX code. This reduces the readability of the code.
This is code before I save the file

Before Saving the File:
[image: Before Saving the File]

This is File after saving:
[image: This is File after saving]

I have tried editing VS Code settings

```
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingJsxExpressionBraces": false,
"javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterOpeningAndBeforeClosingTemplateStringBraces": false
```

But it did not help.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Please find a detail step-by-step solution for this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993808/visual-studio-code-changes-format-react-jsx/67938283#67938283

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by manually changing the language of the file to `javascriptreact` instead of `javascript`.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also rename the file changing its extension from .js to .jsx and VSCode will understand that the file is React.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I solved by making **js-css-html formatter** extension disable and closing the vs code and restart