# ReactJS formatting in VS code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using the ReactJS tutorial [here](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

I opened the project in VS Code ver 1.18 by using `> code .`.
After I create a file index.js, then add the code as given:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <button className="square">
        {/* TODO */}
        </button>
    );
  }
}
```

When I hit Ctrl-S to save, VS Code does the following:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (document.render() < button className = "square" > { /* TODO */ } <
    /button>
    );
  }
}
```

Note: the changes  to `<button>`.
All the code gets reformatted.
I checked VS codes for formatting - it is false.
Intellisense  works fine.
I also added `jsconfig.json` in my `src` folder using `"jsx": "react"`.
Is VS code really not usable or am I missing anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115112/how-to-prevent-insert-spaces-in-jsx-code

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to change the default formatting rules in VSCode (you may not be able to).

I would suggest using [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) as a code formatter. Works really well and gives you a lot of control over how the code is formatted. And it can tie into eslint as well.

See [this article on medium for instructions](https://hackernoon.com/configure-eslint-prettier-and-flow-in-vs-code-for-react-development-c9d95db07213) for instructions on how to setup prettier and eslint.