# Eslint airbnb and prettier config removes all spaces after dots in text

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Eslint airbnb and prettier config removes all spaces after dots in lorem ipsum text. All the other spaces remain correct. I configured .eslintrc, .prettierrc, .eslintignore, .prettierignore and .editorconfig when configuring a new react project from the template. What can be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Airbnb ESlint rules include `no-trailing-spaces`. So if you use `--fix` mode, linter may remove all your spaces.

More about Airbnb styles: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my bug in the following way: [How to prevent insert spaces in JSX code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115112/how-to-prevent-insert-spaces-in-jsx-code) . I just manually changed in VS Code Javascript to Javascript React.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing prettier altogether, and I just run eslint with --fix instead, as I found prettier had styles that contradicted my `.eslintrc` file.

There are plug-ins for VS code that will run your eslint rules on save, similar to prettier, like this one:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint