# Why does my App.js code changes itself upon save?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to build my first React Native app. I am using the default App.js code, the only difference is the output text that I changed from `Open up App.js` to `Hello world!`. I have an issue with the code changing itself upon save.

This is how the default function looks before I press Ctrl+S to save the file:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And this is how the default function looks after the save:

```
export default function App() {
    return ( <
        View style = { styles.container } >
        <
        Text > Hello world! < /Text> <
        /View>
    );
}
```

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Its more than likely the ide/editor you are using and the settings within it

Comment: It is because of the autosave format change in the settings.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the language or the library you're using, please check your IDE settings.

Comment: What IDE you are using for this ?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: I have autosave disabled by default, so I am not sure what should I change in the settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent insert spaces in JSX code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115112/how-to-prevent-insert-spaces-in-jsx-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on your IDE. Since you are using Visual Studio Code as IDE try to use code formatting extension to format your code accordingly.

Try to use Prettier - Code Formatter Extension for VS Code -> [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode)

If you wan to **enable** auto save add the following to your settings.json file:

> "editor.formatOnSave": true

If you wan to **disable** auto save add the following to your settings.json file:

> "editor.formatOnSave": false

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS code...
I got the same problem and I just solved it by:

1. Click on the button in the bottom left probably saying
   "Javascript"
2. Click on it and a search bar will appear
3. Type "react" and choose each of the two either "react
   (javascriptreact)" or "react (typescriptreact)" depending on what
   you are using

Hope that helped solve your issue if not...

1. `ctrl+shift+p` to open a the search bar
2. type "open settings"
3. click "open settings(JSON)"
4. paste this at the end of the .json file: `editor.formatOnSave": false`

Answer (score 0):

*Attention: Select the appropriate language mode.

Please see below for details:

[Programming language: Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrBc7.png)

[Programming language: Javascript React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj3C4.png)