# after vscode format code the program doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-redux, jsx

When i save file index.js vscode format it from

```
render(
  <Provider store = { store }>
    {routes}
  </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

to

```
render( <
    Provider store = { store } > { routes } <
    /Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

after that the program doesn't work and i have error message

```
React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.
```

What settings in vscode i need to change to fix this bug?

Comment: did you do any searches? I mean, there's a question right here on SO with a solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993808/visual-studio-code-changes-format-react-jsx

Comment: Basically it messed up your code. the close tag `</Provider>`  has been split over 2 lines. The opening tag has also been split. Put them back and it should work, and turn off VSCode autoformat option :)