# How to make VS Code recognise HTML syntax in return React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am using React to build a front end, using the `create-react-app` package to generate a boilerplate. When going into any js file that has embedded HTML, when I save, the HTML goes all askew, everything compiles correctly, but the formatting looks horribly off. The image below shows how my code looks after save...

[image]

I know I could go to my settings and set

`"editor.formatOnSave": true`

However, I lose formatting on saving on all other files, which I would prefer to have.

Are there any extensions/settings so that when I save a js file with embedded HTML that it formats the HTML code?

Comment: Check the same issue here – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993808/visual-studio-code-changes-format-react-jsx

Comment: @chuve Yes, it was an installed formatting extension `Beautify` causing this, noticed just before you posted your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of this for anyone that may come across it.

The extension `Beautify` was causing the code for format incorrectly.