# i am getting an error in visual studio code in javascript files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am getting an error while saving file , in **visual studio** code in *Java script* files while saving file all code is getting jumbled up ,  am stuck please help [vs code error file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApflW.png)   tried many extensions but  am unable to solve my problem please help me

Comment: Don't post images of the code. Post your code right here in stackover flow

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio code changes format (React-JSX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993808/visual-studio-code-changes-format-react-jsx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your formatting is all messed up. Your html(jsx) tags are formatted like this:

```
<
Header />
```

Try formatting it like this:

```
<Header />
```

Comment: i didn't do that its getting auto formatted in that way when hit save file

Comment: Okey. This means your formatter is probably not configured correctly. Maybe you can find something here to figure out how to configure your formatter: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings. You can also take a look at prettier: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode